# Prevent confirmation dialogue from opening when there's a validation error

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog, message

I have a text area inside a tab of accordion panel which is a description. I am trying to edit a description and saving it. I am validating the text area so that max character shouldn't exceed 1000 character. I am using `<p:message>` to display validation message. Before the actual save, a confirmation dialogue will be shown to confirm the save.

```
<p:messages showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />

<p:accordionPanel dynamic="true">
    <p:tab id="_0" title="description">
        <p:inputTextarea styleClass="max" id="editDesc1" widgetVar="txtBox" value="#{testBean.description}" 
            rows="6" cols="150" validatorMessage="#{msg.AddSystem_validationMsg5}" autoResize="false">
            <f:validateLength maximum="1000"></f:validateLength> 
        </p:inputTextarea>

        <p:commandButton value="save"  oncomplete="saveDialog.show()"/>

        <p:confirmDialog message="#{msg.EditSystem_confirmMsg1}" width="200" 
            showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" 
            header="Confirm" severity="alert" widgetVar="saveDialog"> 
            <p:commandButton value="#{msg.EditSystem_confirmAnswer1}"  action="#{testBean.saveEdit}" process="@this" /> 
            <p:commandButton value="#{msg.EditSystem_confirmAnswer2}" onclick="saveDialog.hide()" type="button" />
```

If an user enters more than 1000 characters and tries to save it, then the validation message appears for a short time and then the confirmation dialogue pops up, causing the validation message to disappear. How do I prevent the confirmation dialogue from popping up when there is a validation error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check in `oncomplete` of the save button if validation hasn't failed. PrimeFaces puts a global `args` object in the JavaScript scope which in turn has a boolean `validationFailed` property. You could make use of it:

```
<p:commandButton value="save" oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) saveDialog.show()"/>
```

This way the confirm dialog will only be shown if the validation has not failed.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use javascript to validate:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
// validation here
if(isValidated){saveDialog.show()}
else alert('exceed ...');
}
</script>
<p:commandButton value="save"  onclick="test()"/>
```

Comment: This completely defeats the purpose and powers of server side validation. This approach is absolutely not recommended.

Comment: Yes, i forgot args.validationFailed, so i recommend that, thank !